# why is html5 form input saying required when optional

Tags: html, node.js, forms, input

So I have a html5 form with input fields. Lets say the fields are first name, last name, phone, email, and address.

Now first, last, and address are required while phone and email are optional. I know that the backend has this configured properly. However on the html5 form it will not let me submit without phone or email otherwise it returns a 400 error.

If I remove the optional from the html5 form, it will let me submit it or I can put in a value=" " and will submit also. I can even tag the fields with CSS3 using :required and :optional and it will show appropriately but still won't let me submit.

Now I obviously can't just remove the optional from the html because some users may need those fields but I also don't want to send a default value of " " or "n/a" for users who don't need them. Am I just doing something wrong here or what? I don't get what is going on.

edit 2: This is a node.js api using Hapi.js with Joi validation, request, and couchdb.

edit: I know that 400 is a server error but if I post with a curl omitting the optional ones it goes through fine. It also goes through fine when I remove the optional ones from the html which is why it doesn't make sense. Here is the validation code server side for the api.

```
handler: function(req, res) {
request({
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'https://127.0.0.1:6984/banned',
        jar: cookieJar,
        strictSSL: false,
        json: {
            firstn: req.payload.firstn,
            lastn: req.payload.lastn,
            licno: req.payload.licno,
            phone: req.payload.phone,
            email: req.payload.email,
            address: req.payload.address,
            description: req.payload.description
        }
    },
    function(err, resp, body) {
        if (err) { res(err) };

        if (resp.statusCode === 401) {
            res(resp.statusCode + ' Please log in.');
        }
        else if (resp.statusCode === 201) {
            res(body);
        }
    });
},
validate: {
    payload: {
        firstn: Joi.string().required(),
        lastn: Joi.string().required(),
        licno: Joi.string().optional(),
        phone: Joi.string().optional(),
        email: Joi.string().optional(),
        address: Joi.string().optional(),
        description: Joi.string().required()
    }
}
```

Comment: A 400 error is server-side. Show us the server code.

Comment: 400 for HTML5 Validation!!!

Comment: Are you using a Javascript framework or some sort of library? If so, please add the tag or explain in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a friend helped me figure it out. What is happening is that required or not the html form is sending with a value of "" if no data is put in. That is not " ", "null", "undefined" just "". This is not a valid value for the server so it throws the 400 error. The code that fixed it was by checking if the payload exists before validating and sending it through.